# Joining Search Box & Delete Markers in google maps API Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am totally new in Javascript. I have a project to make a program (based on web page) connected to google maps.

i have read developer.google.com and stuck with it.
Please help me, how to joining two sample codes place search box (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) and marker remove (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)

thanks

Update: this is my code (for now)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
   #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input onclick="clearMarkers();" type=button value="Hide Markerr">
      <input onclick="showMarkers();" type=button value="Show All Markerr">
      <input onclick="deleteMarkers();" type=button value="Delete Markerr">
    </div>
 <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initAutocomplete() {
  var Markerr = [];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -7.266813, lng: 112.770218},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
  
  
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
  // -----------------------------
  // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
        map.addListener('click', function(event) {
          addMarker(event.latLng);
        });

        // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
        addMarker(haightAshbury);
  
  // *********************************
      }
  // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });
        Markerr.push(marker);
      }

      // Sets the map on all Markerr in the array.
      function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Markerr.length; i++) {
          Markerr[i].setMap(map);
        }
      }

      // Removes the Markerr from the map, but keeps them in the array.
      function clearMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(null);
      }

      // Shows any Markerr currently in the array.
      function showMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(map);
      }

      // Deletes all Markerr in the array by removing references to them.
      function deleteMarkers() {
        clearMarkers();
        Markerr = [];
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: haightAshbury is not defined`

Comment: thankyou @geocodezip for your response. 
Actually i am not sure that i am in the right wat (while code it). 
Could you help me to joining code in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You have errors in the posted javascript.

1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: haightAshbury is not defined`
2. `Uncaught ReferenceError: Markerr is not defined`
3. ...

The main problem is that the `markers` array and the `map` variable are not in the global scope, once those are moved to the global scope and the references to the `Markerr` array removed (or changed to `markers`), the buttons work (or at least do what I expect).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kcx91g2n/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// global variables
var markers = [];
var map;
function initAutocomplete() {
  // initialize the global map variable 
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -7.266813,
      lng: 112.770218
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  var floatBox = document.getElementById('floating-panel'); map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(floatBox);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // -----------------------------
  // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });

  // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
  // addMarker(haightAshbury);

  // *********************************
}
// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.

function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

// Sets the map on all Markerr in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

// Removes the Markerr from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setMapOnAll(null);
}

// Shows any Markerr currently in the array.
function showMarkers() {
  setMapOnAll(map);
}

// Deletes all Markerr in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
  clearMarkers();
  markers = [];
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" /><br>
  <input onclick="clearMarkers();" type=button value="Hide Markerr">
  <input onclick="showMarkers();" type=button value="Show All Markerr">
  <input onclick="deleteMarkers();" type=button value="Delete Markerr">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @geocodezip
i've try my own, and adapt it to my structure. it is really work. Thanks again

Comment: If this answered your question, [please accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)